# Allowing multiple IP ranges access to a virtual host in lighttpd with remoteip

Tags: ip, lighttpd

Say I'd like to restrict access to a virtual host to **multiple** IP ranges. How to do that? The Perl regex syntax style doesn't work, and i don't want loose restrictions like *10.**

The code below works for a single range:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "adm.example.org" {
    $HTTP["remoteip"] != "10.0.0.0/28" {
            url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really need ranges, not single IP addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$HTTP["remoteip"] !~ "192.168.2\.|192.168.0\.|^10.8.9\." {
  url.access-deny = ( "" )
}

or to include for the 192.168.0.0 network only this range: 192.168.0.180 - 192.168.0.188

$HTTP["remoteip"] !~ "192.168.2\.|192.168.0.18[0-8]|^10.8.9\." {
  url.access-deny = ( "" )
}
```

Comment: This is it! I used your first configuration, this does what I need.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
$HTTP["host"] == "adm.example.org" {
    $HTTP["remoteip"] != "1.2.3.4|5.6.7.8|9.10.11.12" {
            url.access-deny = ( "" )
        }
}
```

And so forth

Comment: This may work with IP addresses but doesn't with IP ranges. If I do it like that, access is allowed from everywhere.